# Slow loading jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Hi I am building an internal app for my company using jQuery's [autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete) and am finding it tends to start off very slow.  My assumption is that the bottle neck is perhaps adding its elements to the DOM since after the first query it seems to be substantially speedier.  Does anyone know of a way to pre-load these elements on page load instead of doing it for the first time when the user starts typing?

Comment: What server side language are you using?

Comment: PHP but that's not the issue, it is always slower on the first try.  E.G. if I type in `foobar` as the first query and `random` as the next one, random results will show up significantly faster (I have checked the MySQL queries and bother are returning at something like 0.01ms)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to use ajax calls to retrieve data, and your autocomplete list isn't too big, you can feed the data for autocomplete from js array of objects.

Lets assume you have such data (that you build as early as you want/can):

```
var data = [{"n":name, "p":pagename,"c":number_of_results},...];
```

Then autocomplete call would look:

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete(data, {
    matchContains: true,
    formatItem: function(row, i, max) {
        return row.n + " ("+row.c+")";
    },
    formatMatch: function(row, i, max) {
        return row.n;
    },
    formatResult: function(row) {
        return row.n;
    }

});
$("#autocomplete").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
    if(!data) {
        alert("Please select an item");
    } else {
        window.location.href =  data.p;
    }
});
```

This will create an autocomplete that would look like `item name (number of results)`, and on clicking on an item it would redirect to a corresponding item pagename.

I have about 1,000 items and the autocomplete speed is instant.

Answer (score 0):

Server side on PHP/SQL is slow.

Don't use PHP/SQL. My autocomplete written on C++, and uses hashtables to lookup. 
See performance [here](http://olegh.ath.cx/autocomplete.html).

This is Celeron-300 computer, FreeBSD, Apache/FastCGI.

And, you see, runs quick on huge dictionaries.
10,000,000 records isn't a problem.

Also, supports priorities, dynamic translations, and another features.